# How to setup suffix proxy server

Tags: proxy

Can anyone guide me for setting up suffix proxy server , so that user can access some specific sites cached in our campus server without doing any configuration in their browsers.

by suffix proxy i mean that if user wants to open http: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server page then he should enter link:

http ://en.wikipedia.org.CAMPUSPROXY.NET/wiki/Proxy_server (where campusproxy.net is our proxy server) and this requested page can be retrived from our proxy server in place of wikipedia.org

Comment: The script is on SuffixProxy.com its rather simple, Xproxyhost.com will also set it up free if you host with them, just submit a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

It's a redirect really - your server needs to have a url check that will catch the prefix portion of the url and for this you obviously need unlimited prefix's available from the registered domain URI then it just reforms the uri of the prefix makes the request for the page and then presents it as content to the user - normally you'll also inject a banner at the top of the page also.

so it goes

`User - http-get en.wikipedia.org.CAMPUSPROXY.NET/wiki/Proxy_server`

your server takes this and creates `"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server"` via a script or what have you.

`CAMPUSPROXY.NET http-get en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server`

inject the banner code into the webpage via a script or what have you.

probably also modify the html tags and headers to include your prefix proxy info

some knowledge of python - perl or whatever is all you need together with apache or similar server, their are of course scripts out there already but if you do that you'll learn nothing.